# IIS Url-Rewrite: URL won't get recognized

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm facing a problem with the URL-Rewrite module right know.

What I want to achieve:
I have a website with the address "test-server" right now. When the URL is typed in I want to change the URL to "test-server/de" or "test-server/en" through the {HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE} variable. 
This should only work on the URL "test-server" so when a user is on a sub-page like "test-server/de/" he can manually change the URL to "test-server/en/" without getting redirected again.

This is what I have right know:

```
<rewrite>          
        <rules>              
            <rule name="ToGermanPage" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^de" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern=".+test-server" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="ToEnglishPage" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^test-server" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://test-server/en" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^de" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My problem is that if I type the following:
    
It won't recognize the URL, same goes for the {URL} parameter inside the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this rule...

```
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" pattern="^de" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern=".+test-server" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

The `match url` is `.*`, which will match all resources. If you only want your redirect to work for `http(s)://test-server/`, you should specify a blank resource (`url="^$"`).

You could use `{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `{URL}` to match just your hostname (without worrying about `http/https`).

Also, your redirect URL is using `{R:0}` which is the *match/resource* URL. For `http://test-server`, the *match* URL is blank, since no resource path is specified. You should be able to just remove `{R:0}` altogether from your redirect URL, though, since you just need to redirect to `de` or `en`. So, try something like this:

```
<match url="^$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test-server$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

That should match `http(s)://test-server` and redirect to either:

```
http(s)://test-server/en
```

or

```
http(s)://test-server/de
```

depending on the value of `{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}`.

Comment: This did the trick, except for the <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}" appendQueryString="true" />. When the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE == "en-GB" it would redirect to "test-server/en-GB", but everyone else was exactly what I was missing.